# How do I remove a specific chapter from a table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, revtex

My current layout looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{revtex4}  

\tableofcontents

\section*{Acknowledgements}
\section{Chapter 1}
\section{Chapter 2}
\section{Chapter 3}
\section{Chapter 4}
\section{Chapter 5}
\section*{Appendix}
```

How do I remove the * sections (Acknowledgements and Appendix) from the contents page?

Although this question has been asked, I can't find a reasonable answer.

Comment: It isn't removed by default.

Comment: @Matt Hill Hello and welcome on TeX.SE! Did you make sure to compile at least twice in a row? The table of contents is generated using the `.aux` file, therefore at least two passes are required (in general enough, but not always sufficient!) to get a stable TOC. The second run is required to get table of contents titles right. This can offset things and thus change page numbers. Hence the need for a third run when you are producing the final version of your document. I don't think a fourth run can change the TOC, unless you are doing very custom TOC formatting where page nums can shift lines.

Comment: Correction: in my previous message, read `.toc` rather than `.aux`.